# --fixupoverflow=warn is being ignored by the MPLAB X Linker

Tags: pic, assembly, mplabx, assembler

I have tried several hours worth of variations and I am at my wit's end on this one.
The MPLAB-XC8-PIC-Assembler-User-Guide-50002974 clearly states:

> The --fixupoverflow option customizes the action taken by the linker
> when a fixup overflow situation is encountered.

"-Wl,--fixupoverflow=warn" is the option I want. Because it will automatically apply the appropriate mask to addresses.  Without it, you have to apply the mask manually on every single line that needs it.  (I am converting legacy code and there are thousands)

But, when I plug it in - the linker basically says NO!  I am going to ignore that and give you an error anyway.  Thus refusing to compile code.  I have tried with and without the "-wl," header.  I have tried passing the option from the assembler, I tried putting it as an additional option at the end, I have tried cutting/pasting the exact phrase from the manual, etc... etc...  The linker ignores ALL of it.

Here is a snip from the linking phase of the compilation:  Note that it does NOT complain about the option or give any kind of error AT ALL on the options list - which makes it appear that it is accepting the option.  But - Yet - it ignores it.
Note that the first error is for this code:  "MovLW Osc8R+1" where Osc8R is a label at address 2FFE.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.36\pic-as\bin\pic-as.exe" -mcpu=PIC18F14Q40 build/default/production/Speakjet2.o \
-o dist/default/production/Speakjet2.X.production.hex \
 -misa=std -msummary=+mem,-psect,-class,-hex,-file,-sha1,-sha256,-xml,-xmlfull -Wl,--fixupoverflow=warn -mcallgraph=std -Wl,-Map=dist/default/production/Speakjet2.X.production.map -mno-download-hex
./Interrupts.inc:28:: error: (1357) fixup overflow storing 0x2FFF in 1 byte at 0xD6/0x1 -> 0xD6 (build/default/production/Speakjet2.o 38/0xBE)
./Interrupts.inc:149:: error: (1357) fixup overflow storing 0x2FB5 in 1 byte at 0x122/0x1 -> 0x122 (build/default/production/Speakjet2.o 38/0x10A)
./Interrupts.inc:166:: error: (1357) fixup overflow storing 0x2FC5 in 1 byte at 0x13E/0x1 -> 0x13E (build/default/production/Speakjet2.o 41/0xC)
./Interrupts.inc:173:: error: (1357) fixup overflow storing 0x2FA0 in 1 byte at 0x148/0x1 -> 0x148 (build/default/production/Speakjet2.o 41/0x16)
```

Any idea on how to get the linker to do what the manual says it will do?

Comment: I suspect that these are errors despite the warning you wanted and, because they are errors they need manually fixing individually.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I thought of that too.... but that isn't it.  The error "storing 0x2FFF in 1 byte" is covered in the manual.  It means the value is too big to fit in a byte.  Solutions given are:  Manually mask OR change the overflow response to "warn". Additionally, the responses are spelled out for the various options:

"error" Trigger an error message  <---  default
"warn" Truncate the value to fit and trigger a warning message.
"ignore" Truncate the value to fit and continue with no notification
of the fact.

But you did give me an idea... I didn't try "ignore"

Comment: Nope!  "Ignore" doesn't ignore the error.

Comment: The Manual is here:
(Section 6.1.31)
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/DEV/ProductDocuments/UserGuides/MPLAB-XC8-PIC-Assembler-User-Guide-50002974.pdf

Comment: Did you try to prefix with `-Xlinker --fixupoverflow=warn`?